# Preventing page reload upon form submission to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, forms

I have seen some questions similar to mine but not quite the same, so if this is a duplicate, sorry.  I am using the javascript hide and show functions to attempt to hide the "thank you" message after they submit the form, which submits the information to a database, and that works fine, but I have been unable to prevent the page from going to the next page.  It always goes to /about_you.

I have tried using onsubmit = "return false" at the top of the form, and it completely prevents the form from submitting.  Have tried onclick="return false."  I am not quite sure how to implement an jquery function.  Don't know much of anything at all about jquery, so if the answer involves jquery, please give me as much detail as you can.

I am just attempting to make the page load a "thank you for completing the survey" afterwards.  It is a 1-page webpage, so going to another duplicate version of the webpage isn't viable.  Any help is extremely appreciated.  Thank you.

this is the javascript function.

```
function hideyou(){
    document.getElementById("about_you_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("thank_you").style.dislay = "block";
}
```

this is the submit

```
<input id="about_you_submit" type="submit" onclick="hideyou();" value="Submit">
```

this is the code i put in ruby.

```
post '/about_you' do

fname = params[:fname]
lname = params[:lname]
address = params[:address]
address2 = params[:address2]
city = params[:city]
state = params[:state]
zip_code = params[:zip_code]
email = params[:email]

db.exec("INSERT INTO public.users (fname, lname, address, address2, city, state, zip_code, email)
VALUES ('#{fname}', '#{lname}', '#{address}', '#{address2}', '#{city}', '#{state}', '#{zip_code}', '#{email}')")
```

Comment: `target=` a hidden or not hidden iframe from the <form> tag

Comment: I would love to know multiple ways to do this.  Please elaborate on what you mean.  If I had a form labelled fname, I would put...target=fname inside the submit tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to submit form without page refresh. Now you can submit the form, the data is send and saved into DB, but javascript:

```
document.getElementById("about_you_form").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("thank_you").style.dislay = "block";
```

unable to execute and do its work , because browser is redirected (you are making request to /about_you). What you need to do is simple AJAX request (sending data in the background, browser stays in the same page and after successful sending and response from the server - javascript kicks in)

Change your **hideyou** function as:

```
function hideyou(e, btn){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(btn).parents('form');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      document.getElementById("about_you_form").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("thank_you").style.dislay = "block";
    }
  });

}
```

Then change

```
<input id="about_you_submit" type="submit" onclick="hideyou();" value="Submit">
```

To

```
<input id="about_you_submit" type="submit" onclick="hideyou(event, this);" value="Submit">
```

Comment: anything you can add to just help me understand what is going on there.  The url, data, serialize...I assume the success:  is basically (onsuccess run this function) and the $(btn).parents('form), basically the whole thing, i am unfamiliar with.  But it worked great and thank you so much!

Comment: ok.  I have been playing around with it.  I start the page off by running a hide function that hides the thank you message.  Your code worked wonderfully, except that it does not load the thank_you message.  I have the hideThankYou function at the very bottom of the page in the beginning, and the hide works.  Is that hide function blocking your code from showing the thank_you id?  this is that function

Comment: You dont have to use function to hide thank_you message by default. Instead: on the html element with id="thanks_you" (or whatever it is called) add inline style style="display: none". This way you dont have separate javascript for hiding the message by default.

Comment: Thats something I never would have considered.  But the reason it wasn't displaying was a small typo.  the "thank_you" getElementById had "dislay" instead of display.  I didnt see it until today.  But your way seems more efficient, less hackey.  Thanks for everything.